# EPPLUS import excel file without header ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hi is it possible to read an excel file without headers using EPPLUS?

Comment: Headers aren't anything special in excel - they're merely cells. So I would assume it can, yes. What *specific* problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to read an excel file that has no headers. I checked other sources and I cannot seem to find an example of reading an excel file without headers. Although I've seen some examples that can read with headers.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/277/reading-excel-files-without-saving-to-disk-in-asp-net

I'm following this example and yes, it does need a header. I'm looking for something that doesn't require a header to be read.

Comment: Then take that example and modify it slightly. Remove the part that reads the headers and then have the second loop start at index `1` rather than `2`. You can't really expect code to be delivered to you specifically tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the excel in csv format and skip the first line after reading all line.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName).Skip(1);
```

or you can use oledb connection to import data from excel to datatable .

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + filename + ";" + "Extended  Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';";

string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", tablename);
        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
        {
            DataSet jobDataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(jobDataSet, "jobInfo");
            DataTable jobDataTable = jobDataSet.Tables["jobInfo"];
        }
```